# Date validation already taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have a `Schedule` model which has a `start_date` `date` field and a `type`.

Multiple `Schedules` are allowed to exist with the same `start_date` when their `type` is non-`nil`.

`validates :start_date, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :if => Proc.new{ |schedule| schedule.type == nil } }`

`server »  Schedule.where(start_date: s.start_date).count`

2 of their `.type`s are non-nil, 1 is `nil`. Yet I'm getting an error for this `Schedule`, saying

`s.errors
=> {
  :start_date => [
    [0] "has already been taken"
  ]`

But it seems to only be taken by itself. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think you can't use ":if" as a parameter to :unique -- it applies only to the whole line. You could try using a separate validator:

```
validates :start_date, :presence => true
validates_uniqueness_of :start_date, :if => Proc.new{ |schedule| schedule.type.nil? }
```